# How to format text with multiple periods in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have text with numbers that I need to format in Excel.  The format I tried using in excel is 00000.0000.0, which would work beautifully if it weren't for the double periods.

19271.23.8 -> 19271.0023.8

Can excel format text in that way or am I going to have to use this formula (which works)?

=CONCATENATE(TEXT(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1,1)-1),"00000"),".",TEXT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)),"0000.0"))

I ask because (a) it would be interesting to know the limits of Excel's formatting feature and (b) the above is really difficult to remember.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: number formatting does not apply to text values and literal string `19271.23.8` is a text value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as they are numbers, Excel can provide special formatting. Otherwise, I'm afraid there's no way around but formulas or VBA.

As for your formula, it can be shortened a bit:

> =TEXT(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1),"00000.")&TEXT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)),"0000.0")

Couple of things I used here:

- `&` can be used to concatenate instead of the `=CONCATENATE()`.
- `FIND()`'s last parameter is optional and although you omitted it in your second `FIND()`, you used it in the first, not sure why.
- I removed the dot in between, because you can actually add that in the custom formatting of `TEXT()`

But yes, it's still a bit hard to remember.